# I am trying to not get a variable to ask for input a second time in Python 3.4

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x

Ok, so I know this is probably really simple, but it is just passing over my head. I am making a program for my programming class and I just cannot figure out how to only get my program to just ask for input once and not twice. I need the input from the first function to complete a math problem in another function. Here is what I have:

(As a note, I am not allowed to use global variables. And from what I have seen, I don't want to get into the habit of using them.)

```
def getNum ():
  v = float(input("Give one number: "))
  w = float(input("Give another number: "))
  x = float(input("Give some other number: "))
  y = float(input("Give your favorite number: "))
  z = float(input("Give one more number: "))
  return v,w,x,y,z

def mathNum():
  v,w,x,y,z = getNum()
  total = v + w
  altTotal1 = v + x
  altTotal2 = w + y
  ans = total * (altTotal1 + altTotal2)
  return ans

def main():
  v,w,x,y,z = getNum()
  print("Your first number is: ", v)
  print("Your second number is: ", w)
  print("Your third number is: ", x)
  print("Your fourth number is: ", y)
  print("Your fifth number is: ", z)

  ans = mathNum()
  print("Your answer to the random problem is: ", ans)
main()
```

Comment: You should not call the `getNum()` again, but send the values as parameters in the `mathNum()` function. `mathNum(v, w, x, y, z)` will do the trick

Comment: You call `getNum()` twice. What is the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `getNum()` again in `mathNum()`, pass in the numbers you already have as arguments:

```
def mathNum(v, w, x, y, z):
    total = v + w
    altTotal1 = v + x
    altTotal2 = w + y
    ans = total * (altTotal1 + altTotal2)
    return ans

def main():
    v, w, x, y, z = getNum()
    print("Your first number is: ", v)
    print("Your second number is: ", w)
    print("Your third number is: ", x)
    print("Your fourth number is: ", y)
    print("Your fifth number is: ", z)

    ans = mathNum(v, w, x, y, z)
    print("Your answer to the random problem is: ", ans)
```

Now all that `mathNum()` does is do the calculations based on the numbers passed in as arguments. How you obtained those numbers is no longer `mathNum()`s responsibility.